# How to access external mysql database in android? Which library for http requests?

Tags: android, mysql, database, http

I already am planning to use php to access the actual database then post the data so that the android app can then proceed to grab it.  I am using the database to store longitude and latitude of geopoints for a location based application.  I have my map drawing and class for drawing overlays I am just not sure where to start from here.

I want to use http requests to call a php file that will grab geopoints from the mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`AndroidHttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) if you want and also the Apache `DefaultHttpClient`.

You'll just have to make a `RestService` in `php` that will give you the data you need. You will execute `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` and you can return data in `XML` or `JSON`. Then you can parse it in `Android` using [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) or [JSON](http://json.org/java/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and tips. Maybe I can get something working to just grab the longitude and latitude for right now and see how that works first.