# Fetching data from mysql using an android based client

Tags: java, android, mysql, linux, sockets

I have a server, that is developed using JAVA (netbeans), and a client which is an ANDROID device, I have a very simple database in mysql which runs on the server, all I want to do is to fetch the data using my android client, from the remote sever. where server and client are connected via Wifi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access external mysql database in android? Which library for http requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502976/how-to-access-external-mysql-database-in-android-which-library-for-http-requests)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a RESTful web service on your server that would take HTTP requests from the Android client and return HTTP responses using JSON.